# How can I avoid unmounting the component on on redirect to another component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router

How can I avoid unmounting the component on on redirect to another component?
Here is my code
render in app component

```
<SideMenu isOpen={appMenuShown} menu={<Menu />} onChange={appShowMenu}>
        <Page exactly pattern="/" component={HomePage} />
        <Page pattern="/todos" component={TodosPage} />
        <Match
          pattern="/"
          render={({ location: { pathname } }) => {
            const urls = ['/', '/todos'];
            if (urls.indexOf(pathname) !== -1) return null;
            return <Redirect to="/" />;
          }}
        />
      </SideMenu>
```

Page component

```
const Page = (
  {
    component: Component,
    exactly,
    intl,
    pattern,
  }: PageProps,
) => (
  <Match
    exactly={exactly}
    pattern={pattern}
    render={renderProps => (
      <Box
        // We need flex and backgroundColor to cover SideMenu.
        backgroundColor="white"
        flex={1}
      >
        {titles[pattern] &&
          <Header title={intl.formatMessage(titles[pattern])} />}
        <Box flex={1}>
          <Alert />
          <Component {...renderProps} />
        </Box>
      </Box>
    )}
  />
);
```

When I go to todos page, the unmount is called for HomePage component. Why? How can i avoid it? Please help me

Comment: Why do you want to do this? whats the point of it? the unmount is how this framework is designed to work. If you want to make your own routing then you can do this. just only show pages when the route matches but always render them.

Comment: @JohnRuddell Navigator in ReactNative provides ways to not to unmount a component while switching between pages. I have a component which lists about 300 items in a page without pagination. Rerendering takes about 4 secs. Earlier when I used Navigator, it was very fast.